# Getting Error while integrating the chat gpt into Power BI

Tags: powerbi-desktop, chat-gpt-4

`(message as text ) as text => let url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", apikey = "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" , headers = [        #"Content-Type" = "application/json",        #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & apikey    ], body = Json.FromValue([ model = "gpt-3.5-turbo", messages = [{[role="user", content=message]}] ]), response = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=headers, Content=body]), content = Json.Document(response)[choices]{0}[message][content] in content`

I have used this query to integrate the chat gpt in power bi but when i am invoking the function in power bi i is giving me credentials error.

Can any body know the solution for the same

I have used this query to integrate the chat gpt in power bi but when i am invoking the function in power bi i is giving me credentials error.

Can any body know the solution for the same